# Java multi-thread application that reads a single file

Tags: java, multithreading

I currently wrote my program to use 32 threads and read 1 file per thread (so 32 .txt files).  The multi-threading has nothing to do with CPU speed, but making 32 calls to BING's api per second is a lot faster than making 1.  Each of the .txt files containing a list of search queries.  I create a thread it reads one line at a time from it's file.  Is it possible to create all 32 threads and point them to a single .txt file??

Comment: I'm parsing big text files and I typically do it like this: one producer is doing the I/O and putting in a queue then as many consumers as I want fetch jobs from the queue.  In your case your unique producer could read the txt file and put one entry per line in the queue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the Producer-Consumer pattern. Have only one thread that reads file and pushes each line/command into [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) (thread safe read and write) using [`put()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#put%28E%29).

All other 32 threads should read from the same queue object by calling [`take()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#take%28%29). They will block if queue is empty, which is nice.

This solution is better because the disk is inherently single-threaded so you won't get much by reading the file concurrently.

Comment: Thanks, that makes changing the input a lot easier than having 32 separate files.

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronize the code that handles the file. Each time you write to the file you open, write and close it. Implement using a monitor and it should be fine.

Could also use java util logging as it is thread safe. If you implement a handler then logging api should take care of the thread safety issues.

Comment: There's no writing involved in the question and this doesn't have a thing to do with logging.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how these threads are implemented. If each has its own reader or input stream on the file, then concurrent reading probably isn't much of a problem. Unless the JVM implementation on the OS implicitly locks a file when an input stream is opened on it and the lock can't be shared across streams.

But you'd be doing a lot of unnecessary work, to be honest. It'd be much better to encapsulate the access to the file in a separate class and pass instances of that to your threads, then have that class do the necessary concurrency handling.